# Cancan 2.0 - restricting permissions to a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have the following in my ability model :

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  #...

  def superuser_rules 
    can  :access, :items    
    cannot :update, :items
    can :update, :items, :foo_attributes
  end

end
```

I have a form which mirrors that by only displaying the foo_attributes nested form.

However, when submitting the form, it says the access is denied to update the item.

Is there a way to circumvent this without adding new routes/actions ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new actions to handle these "special attributes".

First you can clean up the special attributes of the `params`.

```
class UserController
  before_filter :only => [:create, :update] { params[:user].delete(:accepted_at) }
end
```

Then you create a special action to change a special attribute:

```
def accept
  User.find(params[:user_id]).update_attributes :accepted_at => Time.now
end
```

Now you can set different permissions for `create`, `update`, and `accept` actions.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user && user.admin?
      can :accept, User
    elsif user
      can :update, User
    end
    can :create, User
  end
end
```

[Take a look at this too](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Custom-Actions)